# "How to fix recaptcha asking 10-20 times in android webview"

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, android-webview, recaptcha

"I'm beginner in android app development,I'm to build an android webView app.The login webpage which I am using in my app contains google recaptcha(I'M NOT A ROBOT) verification.
when users trying to verifying,recaptcha asking more than 10-20 time every time they open the activity.
If you open the same site in google chrome it asking only once,second time it was not asking for recaptcha(auto tick)

Is it's posiable to make my webview works like google chrome (auto click)"

"I tried adding sync cookies etc."

````
    static boolean ASWP_CAMUPLOAD  = SmartWebView.ASWP_CAMUPLOAD;
    static boolean ASWP_ONLYCAM     = SmartWebView.ASWP_ONLYCAM;
    static boolean ASWP_MULFILE    = SmartWebView.ASWP_MULFILE;
    private static String ASWV_F_TYPE   = SmartWebView.ASWV_F_TYPE;
    private String asw_cam_message;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> asw_file_message;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> asw_file_path;
    private final static int asw_file_req = 1;
    private final static int file_perm = 2;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19";

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vtop);


        AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());

        web = findViewById(R.id.web);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        assert ab != null;
        ab.setElevation(0);

        checkConnection();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18)
        {
            web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            web.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            web.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }


        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        web.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.getDatabaseEnabled();
        web.getSettings().supportMultipleWindows();
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
            }
        });




        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
                web.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                web.loadUrl("about:blank");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            }
        });progressBar.setMax(100);


        web.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            }
        });

        registerForContextMenu ( web);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            web.post ( new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    web.loadUrl ( "https://vtop.vitap.ac.in/vtop/login?logout/" );
                }
            } );
        }

    }

    //checking connection
    protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert cm != null;
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void checkConnection(){
        if(!isOnline()){

            web.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder ( VTOP.this );
            builder.setTitle ( "Connection" );
            builder.setMessage ( "Make sure you are connected to Internet or College Wi-Fi" );
            builder.setCancelable ( false);
            builder.setNegativeButton ( "Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            } );

            builder.setPositiveButton ( "Reload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    web.reload();
                    checkConnection();
                }
            } );

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create ();
            alertDialog.show ();

        }
        else
        {
            Toasty.info(VTOP.this,"Just a second",Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            web.loadUrl("https://vtop.vitap.ac.in/vtop/login?logout/");

        }
    }```

"I expect the recaptcha would ask only one time when the webview opens first time"
````

Comment: web link is (https://vtop.vitap.ac.in/vtop/logout/)